# Unable to get all columns on same on row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and trying to center 3 div blocks using the bootstrap 12 columns style. So each div takes up 4 columns. I want some spacing between these columns thus I added 10px margin to the right. This pushes down the 3rd div to the next row. How do I get my spacing and still keep all 3 columns on the same row?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-lg-4 cust_box">
        <h3>Something</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-lg-4 cust_box">
        <h3>Something</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-lg-4 cust_box">
        <h3>Something</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cust_box{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    background-color: #1A284B;
    color: #fff;
    height: 290px;
    max-width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #162444;
    margin-right: 10px; /*Line that causes issue*/
}
```

Problem recreated in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZeJyr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your class `cust_box` inside the the column. The h3 has margin so that may also be interfering with your layout. You may also want to just use the `row` class instead of `form-group`.

See working Example Snippet. (colors added so you can see what's actually happening)

```css
.cust_box {
  margin: 15px 2.5px;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 290px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #1A284B;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #162444;
}
.cust_box h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
.red {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row yellow">

    <div class="col-sm-4 red">
      <div class="cust_box">
        <h3>Something</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 red">
      <div class="cust_box">
        <h3>Something</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 red">
      <div class="cust_box">
        <h3>Something</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Example without Color

```css
.cust_box {
  margin: 15px 2.5px;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 290px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #1A284B;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #162444;
}
.cust_box h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="cust_box">
        <h3>Something</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="cust_box">
        <h3>Something</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="cust_box">
        <h3>Something</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

with the additional margin you are destroying the bootstrap grid system.
have you tried using padding instead of margin?

apart from this you can customize bootrap a lot!
have a look on this:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

EDIT:
i looked at your code and saw your struggle:
use a inner div like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-lg-4 cust_box">
    <div class="inner">
        <h3>Something</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and use your style on the inner div:

```
.cust_box .inner{
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom:15px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right:10px;
        background-color: #1A284B;
        color: #fff;
        height: 290px;
        max-width:100%;
        border: 1px solid #162444;
        margin-right: 10px; /*should not be an issue anymore*/
    }
```

Comment: Have tried padding but padding doesn't give me the spacing.

Comment: Tried it. The divs get stacked on after another. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZgBgL

Comment: yes, this is because you have no bootstrap in your online example! you need to include bootstrap like in the example of your accepted answer